# Reverse Foreign Key Lookup in Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am trying to write an method that will product a reverse foreign key lookup. The idea is that given a single Rails model class, can I reflect to get all of the ActiveRecord reflections and extract the parent table name and foreign key.

This is trivial for simple has and has_many relationships, even with polymorphism. The difficulty I'm having is handling through relationships. I'm not sure that I need to handle belongs_to as a use case.

Here's the code I have so far

```
def add_association(klass_name, association)
  associated_model = association.class_name
  @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model] ||= {}
  if association.is_a? ActiveRecord::Reflection::ThroughReflection
    add_through_reflection(klass_name, associated_model, association)
  elsif association.is_a? ActiveRecord::Reflection::AssociationReflection
    add_association_reflection(klass_name, associated_model, association)
  else
    raise "Unhandled ActiveRecord::Reflection association type"
  end
end

def add_association_reflection(klass_name, associated_model, association)
  return if association.macro == :belongs_to
  begin
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:macro] = association.macro
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:assocation_class] = association.class
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:assocation] = association
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:table_name] = association.klass.table_name
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:pk] = association.klass.primary_key
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:fk] = association.foreign_key
    @association_hash[klass_name][associated_model][:type] = klass_name if association.foreign_key != klass_name.underscore + "_id"
  rescue StandardError => e
    store_the_error(associated_model, e)
  end
end
```

The `add_through_reflection` method is retrieving the macro, association_class, and association right now. I was running both `ThroughReflection` and `AssociationReflection` through the `add_association_reflection` method but the pks and fks were not correct for `ThroughReflection` types.

Comment: This kinda feels like you're rewriting the `ActiveRecord::Associations` module, could you explain what you mean by `reverse foreign key lookup` ?

Comment: What I need to be able to do is given an id in a table on the database, solve for where does that id appear as a foreign key across the entire database. I can use recursion and reflection to instantiate each object and the related objects, etc. but that is extremely inefficient. Constructing a sql query such as `select id from bars where foo_id in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];` would be much more efficient in retrieving all `Bar`s given a set of `Foo`s. However I need to construct a similar SQL statement regardless of how `Foo` is associated with `Bar` (`:has`, `:has_many`, `:through`, etc).

Comment: so for example if a `foo` has many `a`'s and belongs to a `b`, you want a hash such as `foos = { a: [ object, object ], b: object }`, did i get this right ? and all these objects have `foo_id = the id of the first foo`